# android moving Sqlite DB from internal to SD

Tags: android

I have two questions about the "Move application" feature.

If I'm using "Sqlite" and I'm moving my application from internal storage to SD,
the DB is also moved to the SD? 
all the content of the app including the db will be removed completely form the internal storage?

In case the internal storage gets full, can i move the DB from the internal storage to the external storage and keep all my data?

I tried to find good article about this but no good.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
If I'm using "Sqlite" and I'm moving my application from internal storage to SD, the DB is also moved to the SD?
```

The answer is NO.

When your application is installed on the external storage:

- There is no effect on the application performance so long as the external storage is mounted on the device.
- The .apk file is saved on the external storage, **but all private user
  data, databases, optimized .dex files, and extracted native code are
  saved on the internal device memory.**
- The unique container in which your application is stored is encrypted
  with a randomly generated key that can be decrypted only by the
  device that originally installed it. Thus, an application installed
  on an SD card works for only one device.
- The user can move your application to the internal storage through
  the system settings.